# Do Russian use the Cyrillic Thousands Sign (“҂” U+0482)?

Tags: числительные, сокращения

In English (at least in North America, don't know about other English area) you see things like  `10k` as an abbreviation of 10000. I'm wondering if Russian does something similar, particularly regarding this `҂` symbol I came across in Unicode's Cyrillic block, or is that and its related symbols like `҈` firmly a historic relic?

Comment: Most of these weird symbols were used in (Old) Church Slavonic, not in Russian.

Answer (score 13):

`҂` is indeed a historic relic. It was only used in the [letter-based numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_numerals) (a system where A = 1, B = 2, etc; ҂A = 1000). It is not in active use for at least three centuries.

One can see `10k` (or `10K`) for 10000 in a modern text, but only informally<sup>1</sup> (just like in English). This is an unrelated thing; after all, it's only an abbreviation for convenience, whereas ҂ was the standard way to express a thousand.

---

<sup>1</sup> Outside of certain technical context. For example, `k` may officially stand for kΩ (kOhm) (electrical resistance): 10k = 10 kΩ; 4k7 = 4.7 kΩ. This is standard (more or less) worldwide.

Comment: Re "*Outside of certain technical context*", Specifically: Except when attached to an SI unit. (kΩ, km, kg, etc)

Comment: @ikegami, not quite. Units are obvious; but here, `k` alone is used (attached to the number, not the unit) in electrical engineering. Ohm is implicit, and this doesn't apply to other units. "Take a 10K resistor and a 22 nF capacitor."

Comment: oh, I see what you were saying.

Comment: I'd note that it's also customary to use Cyrillic letter 'к' when speaking informally—like "на счёте осталось 25к". In a very informal context it's also possible to use the "word" "тыр" which is an abbreviation of **ты**сяч **р**ублей.

Comment: Specific for monetary values nominated in rubles one can often see "т.р." used for thousands rubles, e.g. "_1300 т.р._" for 1,300,000 rubles.

Comment: I will also add that in informal usage, the K's stack (2кк = 2 000 000).

Answer (score 3):

No special signs regarding number or quantity are used in modern Russian,
only abbreviations like:

```
5 тыс = 5 тысяч = 5 thousands
1 млн = 1 миллион = 1 million
2 млрд = 2 миллиарда = 2 billions
6 трлн = 6 триллионов = 6 trillions
```

Comment: Here 2 billion stands for 2.000.000.000.000 (european billion) or 2.000.000.000 (US billion)?.

Comment: @OscarGarcia it's US billion (2 000 000 000)